# CKFinder used in CKEditor does not work in my ASP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckfinder, ckeditor4.x

I have downloaded CKEditor & CKFinder. Both controls are integrated that way in my ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyOwnSample.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyOwnSample" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```

I use CKEditor & CKFinder initialisation (described in original documentation)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
        filebrowserUploadUrl: 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
    });

    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, {
        skin: 'moono',
        swatch: 'b',
        onInit: function (finder) {
            finder.on('files:choose', function (evt) {
                var file = evt.data.files.first();
                console.log('Selected: ' + file.get('name'));
            });
        }
    });
```

I checked languages where properly set in both 'config.js' files (that way):
   config.language = 'en';

Verified each corresponding files were existing:

```
ckeditor\lang\en.js
ckfinder\lang\en.json
```

When I use 'Image' button from CKEditor, I have a dialog box with an 'Explore Server' button.
Unfortunately when I click on it, I get this error :
Could not start CKFinder: Language file is missing or broken

I know this message is wrong, because language files are there, and are valid.
So where is my mistake ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CKFinder is having trouble loading `en.json` from the server because the `.json` MIME type is missing from your IIS configuration. Fix it as described here:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_troubleshooting_json

For the PHP version of CKFinder, the fix is the same:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckfinder3-php/quickstart.html#quickstart_troubleshooting_json

Answer (score 0):

I had wrong file path in `resources/views/vendor/ckfinder/setup.blade.php.`
I changed the path to my own and it worked

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/adminpanel/bower_components/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
```