# ASP.Net MVC Application with CKEditor to Azure WebApp gives "Could not start CKFinder: Language file is missing or broken"

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, ckeditor, storage

I have a ASP.Net MVC Application with CKEditor which helps me to create/edit the images with note.

I placed my images in the azure blob storage and trying to edit them using CKEditor. I have added Azure connector in place. The Application is working in IIS and able to access the images from the blob storage and edit them. But after migrating to the Azure Web App its failing to load the language file with the following error:

> "Could not start CKFinder: Language file is missing or broken"

Below link states that mime type is missing and needs to be added:
[CKFinder used in CKEditor does not work in my ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813792/ckfinder-used-in-ckeditor-does-not-work-in-my-asp)

How do I update it in Azure WebApp(PaaS)?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add .json MIME type to your IIS configuration. Please read the docs https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-net/quickstart.html#quickstart_troubleshooting_json

Comment: Yes,Adding below statement resolves the problem. i am able to access blob now.
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: yes its fixed.thanks for the help!!.. but i am not able to make it as correct answer.